# Cross compilation GLIBCXX version link error

Tags: qt, opencv, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm configuring a project for a raspberry and i'm facing a linking error that i don't understand.

#### Context:

Actually, i cross-compiled Qt and everything worked fines.
Now, i'm trying to get opencv working as well to make image-processing in my Qt application.
Instead of cross compiling opencv, I installed it with apt install and synchronized my target sysroot in ~/raspi/sysroot.
To get raspi camera control, I'm using mmal libraries (located on rpi in /opt/vc/lib).
I cross compiled Qt with gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf so qmake is using it as well.
Raspi is running Raspian buster Lite which use a quite old glibc (the reason of using gcc-linaro-7.4.1, recommended in Qt mkspec documentation)

#### Problem:

When I try to compile a simple main.cpp, linker fail when linking opencv libraries:

```
~/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libopenmpt.so.0: undefined reference to `std::random_device::_M_getentropy() const@GLIBCXX_3.4.25'
```

On my raspy, glibc version is

```
$ strings /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

#### Question:

I don't understand How opengl can't make reference to a symbol that it is installed on my raspi for my rapsi?
I tryed to compile this code on the raspi and everything link correctly.
What am i missing?

Annex:
the comand failing

```
~/Documents/personal/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=~/raspi/sysroot -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/qt5pi/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,~/raspi/qt5pi/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,~/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-rpath-link,~/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -o photomata main.o   -L~/raspi/sysroot/opt/vc/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_highgui -lraspicam -lmmal -lmmal_core -lmmal_util -lmmal_vc_client -lmmal_components -lvchiq_arm -lvcsm -lcontainers -lvcos -lbcm_host ~/raspi/qt5pi/lib/libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so ~/raspi/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Widgets.so ~/raspi/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Multimedia.so ~/raspi/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Gui.so ~/raspi/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Network.so ~/raspi/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so -L~/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lGLESv2 -lpthread
```

..................

Thank you for taking the time to read and perhaps help me.

Problem continue at [Missing crt1.o/crti.o for cross compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433765/missing-crt1-o-crti-o-for-cross-compilation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On my raspy, glibc version is

Your question has nothing to do with GLIBC. It's about `libstdcxx`.

> I don't understand How opengl can't make reference to a symbol that it is installed

What's installed on your target system doesn't matter. What matters is which libraries you are linking against on your *host*.

From the [GCC ABI table](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html), you can tell that `GLIBCXX_3.4.25` is first defined in GCC-8.0.0, and that (or later) is the version of GCC that was used to build `libopenmpt.so.0`.

However, you are trying to link this library with `gcc-7.4.1`, and against `libstdc++.so.6` that came *with* it. Since *that* `libstdc++.so.6` doesn't define the needed symbol, your link fails.

You need to either rebuild `libopenmpt` from source using your 7.4.1 compiler, or upgrade to your compiler to gcc-8.0.0 (or above).

P.S. `strings` is the *wrong* way to go about figuring out which versions are defined in a library. Use `readelf -V` instead.

Comment: Thanks for this very clear response!
I was thinking in this way!

I'm writting another issue down this post

Comment: I'm just wondering, You're saying that linker search for libraries on the host?
When you compile a program, it make more sense that linker search for libraries compatible with your architecture and with which the programm will interact (ia in the specified sysroot)

Comment: @Lefix At (static) link time, the linker searches libraries installed in sysroot (on the host). That is the step that is failing. At runtime, dynamic linker will run on the target and will search libraries installed _there_. If static link didn't fail, then the binary would have run ok on the target, since _there_ you have the library which is new enough.,

Comment: Oh ok!
It reassures me I had not been wrong all this time.
I had not done cross compilation for a long time you have put all this clear!
I think my new problem is more of a link error than a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

So compiler version is in cause, there are two options:

- Recompile opencv with gcc-linaro-7.4.1
- Use a >8.0.0 compiler

i've create a new issue at:
[Missing crt1.o/crti.o for cross compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433765/missing-crt1-o-crti-o-for-cross-compilation)

Comment: This isn't an answer. You should either edit your original question, or submit a new one (questions are _free_).